# How to add paging functionality to the Content Query Webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am faced with a big problem while trying to do paging with the Content Query Webpart (CQWP).
I need someone who can answer the following questions:

1. How can I make the CQWP use paging?
2. If you suggest I use some CQWP customized by others, I hope it can be styled by me.
3. Can you give some other advice aside from using CQWP?
4. Is it a good way to solve this problem using the solution mentioned in this article: [SharePoint 2010 Content Query Web Part with paging](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-content-query-web-part-paging/comment-page-3/#comment-220067)?

Comment: Thanks for your editing ,  I think I need to improve my English

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this url to use Paging Content Query Web Part. I deployed this web part and it was done successfully.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/paging-content-query-web-part/

Comment: Can I connect to another webpart in the same page with this this Paging Content Query Webpart?